# Django-REST-Framework: ForeignKey instance is not passed to validated_data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an instance overriding `create` method and passing the `ForeignKey` instance in the data, but that field is not included in `validated_data` passed to `create` method. How can I pass that to `create` ??

I have this model.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email')
    address = models.TextField(verbose_name='Address', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name='User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And here's my serializer.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 2

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        return UserProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Here's my view.

```
class UserRegisterView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
        name = request.data.get('name')
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        address = request.data.get('address')

        if name and email and password:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=email, password=password, email=email)

            request.data['user'] = user
            serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                user_profile = serializer.save()
```

Even though I'm passing `User` object to serializer it's not included in the `validated_data`. Official doc suggests to create another serializer for `User` model and use that, but is there any other way without creating that serializer ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it as [additional argument of save method](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save):

```
serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    user_profile = serializer.save(user=user)
```

From the docs:

> Any additional keyword arguments will be included in the
>   validated_data argument when .create() or .update() are called.