# Django rest framework: Foreign key instance is not being passed to validated_data

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to save data to my database using ModelSerializer but when I pass a ForeignKey instance, it gets converted to string or integer type from instance type after calling is_valid() and this is the error I get:

```
ValueError at /app/core/create-trip
Cannot assign "'ChIJTWE_0BtawokRVJNGH5RS448'": "CityAttrRtTb.attr_nm" must be a "CityAttrn" instance.
```

The error above shows that the CityAttrn instance was converted to its respective field value(and thus its type changed) after calling is_valid().

My problem is basically the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297171/django-rest-framework-foreignkey-instance-is-not-passed-to-validated-data)

The question I linked to above has an answer that I need to pass the foreign key as an argument to the save() method of the serializer only after  calling the is_valid() method.

```py
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save(fk=foreign_key_instance)
```

In this example, I have one data and since I passed the foreign key after is_valid is called, there seems to be no problem. I can do that if I only have one data. However, I am trying to save multiple data at once with .save(many=True) and each of those data have a different foreign key instance. How do I save those kinds of data?

models.py

```py
class CityAttraction(models.Model):
    cty_attr_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cty_nm = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attr_nm = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    des = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'city_attrn'
        unique_together = (('cty_nm', 'attr_nm'),)

class CityAttractionRating(models.Model):
    cty_nm = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attr_nm = models.ForeignKey('CityAttrn', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='attr_nm', primary_key=True, to_field='attr_nm')
    rt_src = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'city_attr_rt_tb'
        unique_together = (('cty_nm', 'attr_nm', 'rt_src'),)
```

views.py

```py
def some_calculation(city_attraction):
    final_result = []
    for cityattraction_instance in city_attraction:
        print(attraction)
        rating_dict["cty_nm"] = "TEST"
        rating_dict["attr_nm"] =  cityattraction_instance # its type is CityAttraction instance right now but it gets changed to string after calling is_valid()
        rating_dict["rt_src"] = 1
        final_result.append(rating_dict.copy())
    return final_result

city_attraction = CityAttractionSerializer(data=request.data, many=True) if city_attraction.is_valid():
city_attraction = city_attraction.save()
calculated_data = some_calculations(city_attraction)
integer_rated_attraction = CityAttractionRatingSerializer(data=calculated_data, many=True)
if integer_rated_attraction.is_valid():
    integer_rated_attraction.save() #how do I save all the instances of CityAttraction here without changing its type to string or integer from "instance"?
```

In the above view, city_attraction is the list of all CityAttraction instances. I need to pass it to the arguments of integer_rated_attraction.save() so as to not lose the "instance" type because of is_valid(). How do I do it?

serializers.py

```
class CityAttractionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CityAttraction
        fields = '__all__'

class CityAttractionRtSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CityAttractionRating
        fields = '__all__'
```

When I pass in the CityAttraction instance to some_calculation function and then performing the validation and saving, I was expecting the model to be saved. But, because calling the is_valid() function changed the CityAttr to the field value("ChIJTWE_0BtawokRVJNGH5RS448" in this case), I got an Value Error exception shown at the top. How would I go about solving this? Thank you!

Comment: What do you call "ForeignKey Model Instance" ? It is not clear to me what you are doing, what the data you are sending looks like or what your serializers look like.

Comment: What type of field are you using in the serializer for the relation?

Comment: Hi. I have completely rewritten the question to make it more clear. Sorry for the inconvenience caused!

Comment: serializer.save(fk=foreign_key_instance) => serializer.save(pk=foreign_key_instance)

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in save.

serializer.save(fk=foreign_key_instance) => 
serializer.save(pk=foreign_key_instance)

Comment: Hi, that was a part of example I wrote to demonstrate what I meant and is not the actual code.

Comment: Yes, but you should use **pk** not **fk**. Model is not have a **fk**.